# Android reports "Could not load libutils.so"

Tags: android, android-emulator

Suddenly I am not able to run my application on an emulator or device giving me this error on the console:

> ActivityManager: link_image[1721]:  3116 could not load needed library 'libutils.so' for 'app_process' (link_image[1710]:  3116 missing essential tables)CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple device clean + IDE restart fixed the issue.